# Powershell not converting properly to csv?

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, date, time

For some reason dates will always be my nemesis and I got a fairly simple issue but can't figure it out. And I know, this issue is one of the most described issues but even with the help of several posts on the net and ChatGPT I still do not have a proper functioning conversion....

New to this customer I have this situation: suppliers send an xlsx file which when placed on our share, will be automatically converted to a csv file. This is done in Powershell (version 5.1.17763.4720) with Import-Excel and Export-Csv.
All files go well but with a new supplier the conversion always ends in numbers, for example 12/09/2023 in Excel becomes 45181 in CSV file (got the same issue with a separate column Time). The files are made at supplier in Excel but never opened in Excel at my side. Personal settings and environmental settings are the same, date and timezone-wise.

Example data Excel is:

```
"Datum";"Tijd";"Prod.code";"Product";"Verwerking";"Extra info"
"12/09/2023";"7:06:34 AM";"550";"XXXX 0-4 MM YYYY";"Actie 1 EN Actie 2";
```

Which is converted to CSV as:

```
"Datum";"Tijd";"Prod.code";"Product";"Verwerking";"Extra info"
"45181";"0.296226851851852";"550";"XXXX 0-4 MM YYYY";"Actie 1 EN Actie 2";
```

Whatever I tried, I keep getting NULL values or this number (related which form of successful or not so successful column selection I try), not the corresponding 12/9/2023. I do know that number represents this date, but it should be shown as a date in the exact form as shown in the original xlsx file (looked afterwards of course). No special parsing but Export-Csv is done for the other files, which are converted correctly and have the exact same file-properties as the one above mentioned.
I am not very acquainted with Powershell so I am looking for a solution in which date (and time) are represented properly while preserving the rest of the file, because at this moment I am struggling more with syntax not even remotely correlated than with this issue itself.

Thanks in advance for thinking along and kind regards,

Aad

Comment: The property of the column is set to general in excel.  Select column and change property to Date

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question as text. Are you using something like `$x = Import-Excel -Path .\org.xlsx; $x | Export-Csv -Path .\new.csv`? For best results, make the code an MRE (Minimum, Reproducible Example).

Comment: @jdweng you are right property is indeed general instead of date as other file have. And to Lit: I tried many different lines of code but your example is the main construct. I tried to select object with the help of column names, but also formulas like 
$date = Get-Date -Date "1899-12-30" -Year ([int]$numericDate / 10000) -Month ([int]($numericDate % 10000) / 100) -Day ($numericDate % 100) -Hour 0 -Minute 0 -Second 0
$row.Datum = $date.ToShortDateString()
or
$excelDate = [System.DateTime]::FromOADate($numericDate)
$excelDate.ToShortDateString() but did not get the wanted result

Comment: Importing data in Excel with wrong format can permanently corrupt the data.  So best way is to use import and select format of each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column values such as `45181` and `0.296226851851852` are examples of date and time-of-day values expressed as [OLE Automation Dates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate#remarks), which map onto `[double]` values in .NET.

- *Date-only* and *combined* date/time values are *automatically* recognized by [`Import-Excel`](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/blob/master/mdHelp/en/import-excel.md) (from the third-party [`ImportExcel`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/) module), *IF* the originating Excel column is *also formatted as a date*, (i.e. with
  a format in the `Date` category), and converted to [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances (whose `.Kind` property is set to `Unspecified`).

  - If the column *isn't* formatted as a date, you can use `Import-Excel`'s `-AsDate` parameter to specify the name of those columns that should be considered dates (and should therefore be converted to `[datetime]`
- *Time-of-day-only* values only display correctly in Excel *if formatted with a format in the `Time` category*, which is *not* recognized by `Import-Excel`

  - However, you can target such columns via `-AsDate` and then extract the time-of-day component from the resulting `[datetime]` instances (which invariably also have a *date* component).

It follows from the above that you have two options:

- If you have control over how the `*.xlsx` files are generated, make them use *string* values representing the dates and times of day, in the desired format, which would be *passed through* via `Import-Excel` and [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv)
- Perform *post-processing* on the `[pscustomobject]` objects emitted by `Import-Excel` in order to create the desired string formats, before passing the results to `Export-Csv`, as shown below:

```
Import-Excel yourWorkbook.xlsx |
  ForEach-Object {
    # If the .Datum and .Tijd property values are of type
    # [double] (numbers), assume they are OLE Automation dates,
    # parse them with [datetime]::FromOADate(), format them
    # as strings as needed, and assign back to the property.
    if ($_.Datum -is [double]) {
      $_.Datum = [datetime]::FromOADate($_.Datum).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    }
    if ($_.Tijd -is [double]) {
      $_.Tijd = [datetime]::FromOADate($_.Tijd).ToString('hh:mm:ss tt', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
    }
    $_ # Output the potentially modified object.
  } # | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation out.csv
```

Note:

- Rather than rely on `-AsDate` for conversion to `[datetime]`, [`[datetime]::FromOADate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.FromOADate) is used for a more robust solution:

  - `-AsDate` would fail for columns with OLE Automation dates that *do* use a format in the `Date` category (which are converted *automatically*).
  - OLE Automation dates *without* such formatting are reported as [`[double]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Double) (double-precision floating-point values) by `Import-Excel`, even if they happen to be *integer* values - that is what the above tests for (`-is [double]`) and then performs explicit conversion to `[datetime]`.
- Your *date* format suggests a day-first representation (e.g. `12/09/2023` referring to 12 September 2023), as you would get in the `en-GB` culture for instance.
- By contrast, your *time* format (e.g. `7:06:34 AM`) suggests an `en-US`-style format, given the presence of `AM`.
- The code above matches these formats, by specifying an explicit format string and passing the *invariant culture* as the culture context. Note that, without passing a culture-info object,  `.ToString()` calls default to the formats of the *culture currently in effect* (as reflected by `Get-Culture` and `$PSCulture`).

Comment: thank you very much for your very detailed reaction. In the notes you exactly described the problem with Excel and CSV and the different formats due to personal and system settings on both sides. Unfortunately I do not have any control over the incoming Excel files so I will go for the solution you give here and try to make sense of the content and formats delivered by this customer.